# How to vibrate phone in Service?

Tags: java, android

I'm programming with android studio. I want a program that vibrates the phone. even if you don't open the app. so it should be in background and I think I have to write it in Service. But it throws an exception. How to fix it?

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Intent i= new Intent(MainActivity.this,Silent.class);
    startService(i);


}
```

Silent service:

```
public class Silent extends Service {
public Silent() {
    AudioManager myAudioManager;
    myAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);

}
```

it throws an exception:

> java.lang.NullPointerException on Silent.java.12

it happens on this line:

```
myAudioManager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
```

Comment: Are you sure the exception is in that line and not the following one? Can you post the complete code and stacktrace?

Comment: @Sebastian Yes, I'm sure exeption is in that line.

Comment: don't do stuff in the constructor. use the `onStartCommand` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest you move your constructor code in onCreate() method of the service, which will be called when your service has been created. Most likely, you are trying to get the audiomanager too early in the service's lifecycle. You can do something like this:

```
@Override 
public void onCreate() {
AudioManager myAudioManager;
myAudioManager = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
myAudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another answer :

Do a broadcast receiver to be triggered on startup.

Or another way to do it is:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    private String TAG = "TAG";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle bundle){
        super.onCreate(bundle);
        Log.e(TAG, "onCreate");
        Vibrator mVibrator = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        mVibrator.vibrate(500);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

You have to add this in the Android Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="nope.myapplicationvibrate" >

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

You need to make a manager to store (and provide) a Context object to be able to use:

(Vibrator) Context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE) method.

Hope it helps.

Comment: unrelated to the issue